# Substitute for --no-undefined in Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a library on Mac OSX that has been compiled successfully on Linux. However, the Apple's ld does not recognise the the flag `--no-undefined`. If I remove this flag, the linking fails with a lot of undefined symbols. Is there any substitute for this flag on Mac OSX?

Comment: If you can provide the ./configure command your using that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traversed the manual for `ld` on Mac OS X and found the solution myself. The flag on Mac is `-undefined error|warning|suppress`. To suppress the undefined errors, flag `-flat_namespace` also needs to be supplied.

Example: `clang++ file.cpp -undefined suppress -flat_namespace`